# Call function when class is deleted/garbage collected

Tags: function, class, lua, destroy

I have a class that opens a sqlite database in its constructor. Is there a way to have it close the database when it is destroyed (whether that be due to the programmer destroying it or being destroyed via Lua's garbage collection)?

#### The code so far:

```
local MyClass   = {}
local myClass_mt= {__index=MyClass,  __gc=__del}

function DBHandler.__init()
    -- constructor  
    local newMyClass = {
        db    = sqlite3.open(dbPath)
    }
    return setmetatable(newMyClass , myClass_mt)
end

local function __del()
    self.db.close()
end
```

Comment: Probably, `self.db:close()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your particular case, according to its [source code](http://lua.sqlite.org/index.cgi/artifact/0680a1f63801d4de35456d4aab6f7c3f41c3931f), LuaSQLite already closes its handle when it is destroyed:

```c
/* close method */
static int db_close(lua_State *L) {
    sdb *db = lsqlite_checkdb(L, 1);
    lua_pushnumber(L, cleanupdb(L, db));
    return 1;
}

/* __gc method */
static int db_gc(lua_State *L) {
    sdb *db = lsqlite_getdb(L, 1);
    if (db->db != NULL)  /* ignore closed databases */
        cleanupdb(L, db);
    return 0;
}
```

But IMO, freeing such resources on GC should be a backup solution: your object could be GCed after quite some time, so SQLite handle will stay open during this time. Some languages provides mechanism to release unmanaged resources as early as possible such as Python's `with` or C# `using`.

Unfortunately Lua does not provide such feature so you should call `close` yourself when possible, by making a `close` method on your class too for instance.

Answer (score 2):

You don't mention what Lua version you use, but `__gc` won't work on tables in Lua 5.1. Something like this may work (it's using `newproxy` hack for Lua 5.1):

```
m = newMyClass
if _VERSION >= "Lua 5.2" then
  setmetatable(m, {__gc = m.__del})
else
  -- keep sentinel alive until 'm' is garbage collected
  m.sentinel = newproxy(true)
  getmetatable(m.sentinel).__gc = m.__del -- careful with `self` in this case
end
```

For Lua 5.2 this is not different from the code you have; you don't say what exactly is not working, but Egor's suggestion on `self.db:close` is worth checking...

Answer (score 1):

look for `finalizer` [in the manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#2.5.1).

Comment: Thanks. I've taken a look at the section of the lua manual you pointed me to and I've come up with the code I've added to my question. I'm a Python programmer by trade so please can you let me know if I'm heading in the right direction with my lua class?

Comment: @JaredGlass I am sorry - I do not really know lua this well (I am a Python guy too). I only found out about the finalizer thing. You'll just wait for the cavalry I guess :)